# Flutter - How to assign conditions to a button?

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox, conditional-statements, textfield

I'm creating an account creation page. It consists of some text fields, checkboxes, and an elevated button.

In the image above, That button is enabled (clickable) only if the above fields are filled and the checkboxes are enabled. Otherwise, it should be disabled (unclickable).

How to achieve this?

Code:

```
Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
                child: Container(
                  width: 310,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _firstnameController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      label: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                            text: 'First Name',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                color: Color(0xffc1c1c1),
                                fontSize: 17,
                                letterSpacing: 0.4),
                            children: const [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: ' *',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    fontSize: 21,
                                  )),
                            ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                    validator: (value){
                      if(value!.isEmpty){
                        return 'This field is required';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                child: Container(
                  width: 310,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _lastnameController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      label: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                            text: 'Last Name',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                color: Color(0xffc1c1c1),
                                fontSize: 17,
                                letterSpacing: 0.4),
                            children: const [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: ' *',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    fontSize: 21,
                                  )),
                            ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                    validator: (value){
                      if(value!.isEmpty){
                        return 'This field is required';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                child: Container(
                  width: 310,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _emailController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      label: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                            text: 'Enter Your Email',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                color: Color(0xffc1c1c1),
                                fontSize: 17,
                                letterSpacing: 0.4),
                            children: const [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: ' *',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    fontSize: 21,
                                  )),
                            ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                    validator: (value){
                      if(value!.isEmpty){
                        return 'This field is required';
                      }
                      if(!RegExp(r'^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$').hasMatch(value)){
                        return 'Enter a valid email';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },

                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                child: Container(
                  width: 310,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _passwordController,
                    obscureText: passwordVisible,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      label: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                            text: 'Enter Your Password',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                color: Color(0xffc1c1c1),
                                fontSize: 17,
                                letterSpacing: 0.4),
                            children: const [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: ' *',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    fontSize: 21,
                                  )),
                            ]),
                      ),
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(passwordVisible ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 187, 187, 187),
                      size: 25,
                      ),
                      onPressed: (){
                        setState(() {
                          passwordVisible = !passwordVisible;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  validator: (value){
                      if(value!.isEmpty){
                        return 'Please enter your password';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                ),
              ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                child: CheckboxListTile(
                  title: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                  text: 'I have read and agree to the',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      color: Color(0xff000000),
                      fontSize: 15,
                      letterSpacing: 0.4,
                    ),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: ' Privacy Policy.',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      fontSize: 15,
                      letterSpacing: 0.4,
                    ),
                    recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () {
                      launchUrl(Uri.parse('https://toy-zania.com/pages/privacy-policy') );
                    }                      
                ),
                ]),
                  ),
                  
                  value: _isChecked0,
                  onChanged: (bool? newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _isChecked0 = newValue ?? false;
                    });
                  },
                  activeColor: Color(0xff82b235),
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                child: CheckboxListTile(
                  title: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                  text: 'I have read and agree to the',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      color: Color(0xff000000),
                      fontSize: 15,
                      letterSpacing: 0.4,
                    ),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: ' Terms & Conditions ',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      fontSize: 15,
                      letterSpacing: 0.4,
                    ),
                    recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () {
                      launchUrl(Uri.parse('https://toy-zania.com/pages/term') );
                    }                      
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: '& Warranty.',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      color: Color(0xff000000),
                      fontSize: 15,
                      letterSpacing: 0.4,
                    ),
                ),
              ]),
                  ),
                  
                  value: _isChecked1,
                  onChanged: (bool? newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _isChecked1 = newValue ?? false;
                    });
                  },
                  activeColor: Color(0xff82b235),
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 320, // <-- match_parent
                  height: 45,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      foregroundColor: Color(0xffe5e5e5),
                      backgroundColor: Color(0xff734FE0),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      createAccount();
                    },
                    child: Text('CREATE ACCOUNT',
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          letterSpacing: 1,
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the `TextEditingController`s and others button/objects that will be responsible to control the button state. Here is an example

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _controller2 = TextEditingController();
  bool isCheck = false;

  bool enableButton = false;

  void _checkFields() {
    enableButton =
        _controller.text.isNotEmpty && _controller2.text.isNotEmpty && isCheck;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(_checkFields);
    _controller2.addListener(_checkFields);
  }
  //dispose them

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _controller,
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: _controller2,
            ),
            Checkbox(
                value: isCheck,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    isCheck = value ?? false;
                  });
                  _checkFields();
                }),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: enableButton ? () {} : null,
              child: const Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```